# How to avoid duplicate dependencies in Gutenberg blocks

Tags: block-editor

The WordPress Gutenberg block build script uses [wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin/) to build the blocks without WordPress dependencies being repeated but what about other dependencies?

If I build a plugin with 10 blocks and they all re-use dependencies, the WordPress build script will embed the dependency in every block bundle.

Is there a good way to handle this without having to re-create webpack build by myself?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dependencies you're using? If they are not part of the ones that the plugin supports, you may need to add a custom webpack config that extends the one provided by @wordpress/scripts

Comment: "without having to re-create webpack build" - if I understand it correctly, no, you don't have to. You could put all your blocks in a single directory and use a single webpack config. As with the code duplication issue, webpack has a [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) you can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress Dependency extraction plugin `@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin` basically makes your ES6 dependency imports use WordPress scripts instead of adding them to the bundle over and over.

This makes modules registered and enqueued in WordPress (including but not limited to `jquery`, `moment` and `react` and `wp.*` modules) to be properly excluded from builds.

You can add additional dependencies to be excluded (make sure you register/enqueue in WordPress) with `requestToHandle` callback.

For example for excluding say `react-sortable` component from build registered as `react-sortable` script in WordPress (PHP),

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new DependencyExtractionWebpackPlugin( {
      requestToHandle: function ( module ) {
        if ( module === 'react-sortable' ) {
          return 'react-sortable'; // WordPress script handle
        }
      }
    } ),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where do you add this?  I am using `wp-scripts build` to build.  The webpack config is hidden.

Comment: In your webpack config file.

Comment: when using `wp-scripts build` the webpack config file is not accessible.  I guess it not possible with that way and have to build custom